# Cannot resolve symbol MyObjectBox

Tags: android, database, greendao, objectbox

I am using object box version 1.1.0. Installed with instructions given in documentation of ObjectBox, but getting this error. Even I searched this issue in FAQ section of Objectbox, the solution they provide is to remove android-apt. But in gradle file there is no android-apt used. So, how to overcome this issue please help me. Bellow is my root level gradle file

```
buildscript {
ext {
    _buildToolsVersion = '26.0.1'
    _compileSdkVersion = 26
    objectboxVersion = '1.1.0'
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    classpath "io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$objectboxVersion"
}
 }allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
    maven { url "http://objectbox.net/beta-repo/"
}
}
 task clean(type: Delete) {
 delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The app gradle file is below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kingof.android"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.001"
    multiDexEnabled = true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
   lintOptions {
      disable 'ValidFragment'
    }
    }
     repositories{
        mavenCentral()
      }
    dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
     core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
       })
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'


compile 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
compile 'com.snatik:storage:2.1.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile "io.objectbox:objectbox-android:$objectboxVersion"


 }apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   apply plugin: 'io.objectbox'
```

Comment: Can you share your app's Gradle file, too?

Comment: @MarkusJunginger app's Gradle file added

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**MyObjectBox** class is generated during build and I think you need to have at least one model file with **@Entity** annotation for it to be generated.

Comment: interesting... this is the first time I have ever tried building before fixing all the lines flagged with errors, but the error *does* go away after the build.

Comment: @Michael if you have errors after do it above. Suppose you use Kotlin, you maybe miss some kotlin configure .
`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' // if using Kotlin
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' // if using Kotlin
apply plugin: 'io.objectbox' // apply last`

Comment: In Kotlin Language cannot find MyObjectBox, even I Defined a class with @Entity annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. In my case, I did not declare the @PrimaryKey attribute in the @Entity class.

```
@Entity
public class Subject {

@PrimaryKey // This line was missing
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private int id;

@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
private String title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same bug, but it was for a very different reason, I had an entity class in a higher level package than the ObjectBox class was, so putting any class with the @Entity tag in the same package or lower than the ObjectBox class solved my problem